# SQL*Plus connection fails in Windows batch script

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus, tnsnames, tnsping

```
call sqlplus UNAME/PASSWD@DBNAME@\\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql
```

> ERROR:
>   ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

```
CALL sqlplus UNAME@DBNAME/PASSWD@\\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql
```

> ERROR:
>   ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Why are you using `Call`? is `sqlplus` a batch file? _if it isn't, remove the `Call` statement and try again_!

Comment: Yes. It is batch file I calling from. Now I can able to connect when I am giving password in the next line but I am unable to connect if I mention Password in the same line.

Comment: Just to confirm, I asked if `sqlplus` was a batch file, and your answer was `yes`; _So you are sending a username, password and `.sql` file as arguments to a batch script named `sqlplus.bat` or `sqlplus.cmd`!_

Comment: Okay. I am not using SQLPLUS.BAT. I am using CALL SQLPLUS from a bat file. Issue was with connection identifier after setting path in command prompt it is working and I have & symbol in my password so it is getting into a new line it seems

Comment: You should first consider removing the `Call` command, or possibly replacing it with the `Start` command. As for your arguments, you should use quotes to protect them and any potentially problematic characters, or escape the characters before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space between the connection string and file (e.g. put a space before the `@\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql`).

```
call sqlplus UNAME/PASSWD@DBNAME @\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql
```

The other thing to try is to fully qualify your DBNAME.  You can look in your tnsnames.ora file (check your Oracle installation folder, and then go to the network\admin folder to find the tnsnames.ora).  In there, search for the DBNAME you're trying to connect to, and see what the full name of it is.
(ex: DBNAME.SRV.YOURCOMPANY.COM would be an example).

Comment: I did. No luck.

Comment: Surprise is I can able to login using  SQL PLUS but using Batch script It will connect from Command prompt there it is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below braces :

```
CALL sqlplus {UNAME}@{DBNAME}/{PASSWD}@\\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql
```

Comment: Still, No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment:

```bat
SQLPlus "UNAME@DBNAME/PASSWD" @\\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql
```

Or:

```bat
Start "" SQLPlus "UNAME@DBNAME/PASSWD" @\\FILELOCATION\SQLFILENAME.sql
```

*Please also enclose your file path with doublequotes, if you wish to protect characters within that too!*